# ensure association is created or saved after primary model has been saved and created Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have these 2 models as follow

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :commitments, class_name: "Commitment", \
    :source => :application, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :commitments

  after_create: update_case_code

end

class Commitment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :application
  after_create: send_notification 

  def send_notification
    ap self.application.case_code
  end
end

class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @application = Application.new(params)
    @application.save
  end
end
```

In my application_controller whenever i create a new Application record,a new record is also created in the Commitment and it tries to get the case_code from the application record but the `after_create` method of the application model hasnt been executed yet.

Is there any way to optimize this code so that it works properly?

Comment: `it tries to get the case_code from the application record but the after_create method of the application model hasnt been executed yet` what do you mean by this. The reason it is calling `send_notification` because `after_create` callback has been called.

Comment: the after_create in the Application Model executes only after the after_create in the Commitment model. I want it to be the other way around

Comment: As you have rightly mentioned and If I have understood it correctly, before creating a record in  `Application` model it goes on to create record in `Commitment` model. As it depends on it

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is. Probably you can also use another callback on the application model which happens before, there are plenty of them. See [Active Record Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

However this is exactly the case, which other people call `rails callback hell`

The best practice here would be just creating a form object, which creates the data in the order you need and remove the callbacks

```
class ApplicationCommitmentForm
  include ActiveModel::Model


  attr_accessor ...

  def submit
    a = Application.create ..
    a.update_case_code
    a.commitments.create ...
  end


end
```

See [ActiveModel Form Objects](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects)

Btw you could also wrap the submit code into a transactions ensuring that either all records are created or in case of any errors nothing at all.